# Flutter google_fonts package doesn't match for roboto flex font

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, google-fonts

Flutter doesn't render robotoFlex fonts Font weights Example Bold, W600, W700, W800, W900,

I'm using google_fonts for my project, I don't know what's wrong. Its working fine with other fonts like GoogleFont.lato and other

font comparison

```
                                  child: Text(
                                    'GoogleFonts.lato',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                    )),
                                  ).pV(5).pH(20),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'This is GoogleF.lato',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 26,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                                  ).pV(5).pH(20),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'This is GoogleF.lato',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 26,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ).pV(1).pH(20),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 35,
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'GoogleFonts.robotoflex',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoFlex(
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                    )),
                                  ).pV(5).pH(20),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'This is GoogleF.RobotoFlex',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoFlex(
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 26,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                                  ).pV(1).pH(20),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'This is GoogleF.RobotoFlex',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.robotoFlex(
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 26,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ).pV(1).pH(20),
                                ),
```

outPut [Here you can see the difference google.lato font renders the font weight but roboto doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqKfu.png)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with the GoogleFonts package and the font in question. You can get what you want if you do it without the GoogleFonts package.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AGCv.png)
Here are the steps:

1. Add the variable font file to your assets (I renamed it to something
   short 'RobotoFlex-VariableFont.ttf'
2. Add it to you pubspec yaml
3. Add it to your code.  I defined it in my TextTheme, then added the code.

Sample Code

```
// pubspec.yaml
//
    fonts:
        - family: RobotoFlex
          fonts:
            - asset: assets/RobotoFlex-VariableFont.ttf

// main.dart
//
    return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            fontFamily: 'RobotoFlex',
          ),

// widget code
// 
    Text(
                    'This is GoogleF.RobotoFlex',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 26,
                      fontVariations: <FontVariation>[FontVariation('wght', 200.0)],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```